# How to install PySide as a non-root in Linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation, python, non-root-user

I want to compile a python programm (GetDistGUI.py) in Linux (CentOs) and whenever I type:

```
chmod a+x GetDistGUI.py
python GetDistGUI.py
```

I get the following error,

```
from PySide.QtCore import QRegExp
ImportError: No module named PySide.QtCore
```

Any suggestions how to solve it? I think I need to install PySide but I can't just,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside
```

because I'm a non-root.

Answer (score 1):

To install PySide as user , you should use `pip` with the `--user` option:

```
pip install --user PySide2
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, I think I have successfully installed PySide2 at `~/.local` and I created a path to it in my `.bashrc` file, but the same error still persists, any other ideas?

Comment: Since the error explicitly mentions PySide and not PySide2 is there any way to install PySide instead of PySide2?

`pip install --user PySide`

does not work...

Comment: @CoolCookie [PySide is depricated](https://github.com/pyside)